# Frontend backend communicate data - best practice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, frontend, backend

I am currently developing a appointment scheduler. Now I am designing my own frontend calendar  (month view) and I know that I will have almost every day an appointment in the database. I had an argue about the API call structure.

He says: I should make an api call which returns a list of every day of a specific month and the days contains the respective appointments. Depending on that I should generate my Calendar.

I say: I want to generate the Structure of the Calendar independent of what i am receiving in the frontend. I will make a call that returns me all appointments of a specific month and add them to the calendar after I received it.

He says my idea has redundance and too much logic in the frontend, because it‘s recommended to keep as much logic in the backend as possible

My question is which way would have a better performance and would be the user experience affected depending on what way I take?

BTW as frontend I use React-Typescript with Redux and as backend C# Core

-

Answer (score 1):

well, I think you should keep a clean separation of concerns. Your API concern is to provide scheduled appointments, which I suggest you to put out like:

```
[
{
"id":1234,
"datetime":"20210115T15:15:00",
"doctor":4231,
"doctorName":"Doe, John",
"patient":9999,
"patientName":"Mary"
}, ...
]
```

and that's it.

How this is going to be plotted on the screen is your front-end business.

I don't know who exactly im favoring here, but `Keep your front-end as simple as possible` is a very minimalistic point of view and likely to overburden your backend with front-end-only aspects.

Answer (score 0):

He is right. Keep your front-end as simple as possible. Logic should be mainly handled by the back-end, Always remember to develop your front-end according to what you receive in your API call.

Comment: My fear is also the user experience is more worse because it takes longer to generate the calendar because you have to wait for the backend.

Comment: this is a very simplistic point of view. The statement `Logic should be mainly handled by the back-end` does not scale and does not allow specialization on the team. I wouldnt be surprise to learn that Musadiq came from a classic Asp.Net WebForms background